# Regex group text in javascript string declaration

Tags: regex

I am making a webscraping utility that GETs a web page source and then regex finds urls that were declared as a string in the javascript. I need to get the text after "`var link\d+\s\=\s\'`" and before " '; "

```
var link1 = 'url i want';
var link2 = 'another url i want';
```

I made a regex101 with what I have so far... [Demo HERE](https://regex101.com/r/qpn0iA/1)

I don't know how to detect multiple numbers if "var link10" or higher, as \d+ does not work in lookaround.

Comment: `\bvar\s+file\d+\s*=\s*([\'\"])((?:(?!\\\1).)+)\1` https://regex101.com/r/IJn5LB/1

Comment: wow. that is one crazy regex. thanks man!